# How to open a Teams card action URL in a collaborative view instead of new browser window?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot that ultimately returns a hero card to a chat message box. This card has an action button that is currently configured to use openUrl, which spawns a new browser window upon click. We now have a requirement to display the same Url in a collaborative view within Teams (i.e. along-side a chat conversation).

I've seen [similar functionality when sharing a document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOiFy.png) via a chat conversation, but can't seem to find any code samples that take this approach for a Url.

Is something like this possible and if so, any ideas how to best implement this approach?

Comment: When you use open URL action it will redirect to browser. This is by Design. But you open open the URL with in the task module when you click on the button, The page need to be publicly available and it should be IFrame. Also you need to add the URL domain to the valid domain, so that you can view the Page inside taskmodule without redirecting to browser. Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

When you use open URL action it will redirect to browser. This is by Design. But you open open the URL with in the task module when you click on the button, The page need to be publicly available and it should be IFrame. Also you need to add the URL domain to the valid domain, so that you can view the Page inside taskmodule without redirecting to browser. Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots) for more info

Comment: I was able to wire-up the action button and display the URL in a task module via deep linking. However, this does not appear to a feasible solution for us. Our goal is to view a URL and chat together about the content, so the obtrusive modal popup experience is not ideal for our needs. I guess we'll stick with opening the URL in a separate browser window, for now.